# Поставить пароль на папку

Tags: windows, windows-10

Как поставить пароль на папку в Windows 10? Есть ли штатные средства? Я запароливаю через WinRaR/7-Zip, но хотелось бы что-то попроще.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft убрали возможность защиты папок паролем в Windows 10. Однако, Вы всё ещё можете установить его при помощи ZIP-архива.

ПКМ по папке -> отправить -> сжатая ZIP-папка.
Затем открываете созданную папку -> Файл -> добавить пароль -> Применить.

Другой способ, не штатными средствами, через WinRar. Там гораздо больше параметров, выбор зависит от того, для каких целей Вы устанавливаете пароль папку.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас Windows 10 Pro (не Домашняя) и несколько учетных записей, то можно через шифрование папки: ПКМ - Свойства - Другие - Шифровать содержимое для защиты данных. Еще можно зашифровать жесткий диск (флешку) целиком через BitLocker. Подробнее читайте здесь: https://neumeka.ru/parol_na_papku.html

Но проще, имхо, через сторонний софт, типа того же WinRaR или через специализированный (Wise Folder Hide и др.).